# AlarmManager setInexactRepeating not triggered repeatedly

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

I am trying to schedule alarm which will perform some task after every hour. For testing purpose, I have set the alarm to trigger after every 5 seconds but it triggers only once.

```
private fun register30MinSchedule() {
        val alarmMgr = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val alarmIntent = Intent(this, AlarmReceiver::class.java).let { intent ->
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(applicationContext, LocationTrack_Service_ID, intent, 0)
        }

        alarmMgr?.setInexactRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis(),
                System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000 ,
                alarmIntent
        )
    }
```

`AlarmReceiver` is called only once. Can anyone please point me the mistake I am making?

Regards,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android repeating alarm not repeating correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30812669/android-repeating-alarm-not-repeating-correctly)

Answer (score -1):

I was able to figure out the issue. All methods of `AlarmManager` requires the precise time. In my scenario, i was using the variable time for 2nd and 3rd parameter `triggerTimeMillis` i.e. `System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000`. So, the correct way of setting repeating alarm is:

```
val initialTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
val repeatingInterval = initialTime + 5000

alarmMgr?.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, initialTime, repeatingInterval,alarmIntent)
```

This is trigger after every repeating interval. Hope this helps.